# How to access body in express.js GET request?

Tags: node.js, rest, http, express, sails.js

I am sending body in GET request in sails.js framework which internally uses express.js

curl -u username:password -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET -d "msisdn=32323" http://localhost:9000/api/v1.1/buy/voucher/raj/32323

i am trying to get the value of msisdn in req.body of express but it is giving me undefined.

I read on internet and it says we can send body in GET request. You can refer this stackoverflow thread.
[HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

Comment: While it's possible it's also not recommended. Either use POST or change URL to ..../buy/voucher?raj=32323

Comment: my java rest server accepts body in GET request . When i am trying with curl request directly to java server it is working fine. But when i use a proxy server made with express.js  I can't recieve the body

Answer (score 2):

With Express it's not possible to send a body with a GET request. http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body.

In reality, you shouldn't even want this [Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.3). If you want to send data with your GET request, query parameters will suffice, if you have the need to send data securely you shouldn't even want to use a GET request in the first place.