# TypeError: arr.slice is not a function in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to do arr.slice and convert it to json for get request but I get error
TypeError: arr.slice is not a function

```
const splitArray = (req, res, arr = shuffled, n = 4) => {
    if (n < 2) {
        return arr
    }
    let size;
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr.length % n === 0) {
            size = arr.length / n
            while (i < arr.length) {
                result.push(arr.slice(i, i += size))
            }
        } else {
            while (i < arr.length) {
                size = Math.floor(arr.length / n)
                result.push(arr.slice(i, i += size))
            }
        }
    }
    JSON.stringify({ result }).then((result) => res.send({ result })).catch()
}

app.get('/cards', splitArray)
```

Comment: Might by any change, `arr` be a string and not an array? What does the console say if you dump out `arr`?

Comment: What is the value of `arr` at runtime ?

Comment: @JohannesKlauß `String.prototype` also has [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Comment: You've set `arr = shuffled`, what is the value/type of shuffled?

Comment: @DaneBrouwer `shuffled` is just the default param, but he uses it with `app.get` so that param gets populated by the framework.

Comment: shuffled is an array of arrays. when I console.log('arr',arr) I get nothing it doesn't appear in the terminal

Comment: Is this using Express? If it is express, the framework will not correctly populate the array as the function should follow the following pattern `req, res, next`.

Comment: when I removed req,res from the function and console.log(arr) it appears as array. so the issue how to read my function in the get request

Comment: Have you tried using the parsed request body?

Comment: how to do it here in get request?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access body in express.js GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339715/how-to-access-body-in-express-js-get-request)

Comment: @DaneBrouwer unfortunately no